# Great wifi adapter

Tags: wireless

I'm looking for a good reliable (one that wont randomly become a brick) long rang 1W+  wifi n adapter. I've looked at alfa and have seen mixed reviews. If you know of any good ones please post them.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Questions like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic on Ask Ubuntu, this one will be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ASUS Wireless N USB Adapter. You can get it here: http://microcenter.com/product/354891/Wireless_N_USB_20_Adapter

It is only $10 after the rebate, and it's fast and works like a charm.